# How i can get window handle of running programs in windows

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I am working on an application that need to enumerate all currently running appications , List their names and take capture from their window as bitmap(for this i need to get HANDLE to the running application window).
i am google about this but can not find any usefull artice or sample code to be my start point.

help me

Comment: You are re-creating the Alt+Tab and/or Win+Tab application switcher…for little purpose. It is already built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for:

**Enumerating processes:**

```
BOOL WINAPI EnumProcesses
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx

an example how to use is in same link

**Enumerating windows**

```
BOOL WINAPI EnumWindows
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx

an example how to use it:
[How to stop EnumWindows running infinitely win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797967/how-to-stop-enumwindows-running-infinitely-win32)

Comment: This is a good start, but `EnumWindows` won't give you a list of currently running applications. It will give you all of the windows that are currently displayed on the current desktop. Which will be *a lot more* windows than you expected.

Comment: i know about mentioned ways.
but how i can get only running application window HANDLE?

Comment: @BenyaminJane Please define precisely what you mean by "running application window HANDLE"

Comment: `EnumWindows` gives you the window handle in the callback function. Is that not what you're looking for, @Benyamin?