# How to find PID of window containing X

Tags: c++, windows, pid, findwindow

I can use `FindWindow`, but the name of the window changes every time I open it. So my question is, how can I either:

A) Find the PID of a window that contains 'x'

B) Find the PID a window with the name of the exe file?

Sorry if the question is obvious, new to C++. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try to use [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) to get all windows handles
2. Check state of windows handle by [IsWindowVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633530(v=vs.85).aspx). [Because some invisible windows can hang the call to GetWindowText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797967/how-to-stop-enumwindows-running-infinitely-win32)
3. Get the title of each windows by [GetWindowText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx). Then check title contains 'X' which characters or string you want.
4. Get pid of it by [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx)

About B/, you can get executable file name by [GetWindowModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633517(VS.85).aspx) via its windows handle.

Comment: Step 2 (`IsWindow()`) is not necessary inside the enumeration callback. Maybe you are thinking of `IsWindowVisible()` instead?

Comment: Your update is [quoting someone else's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797967/how-to-stop-enumwindows-running-infinitely-win32/798003#comment14193164_798003) with no basis behind it. A window's visibility does not affect `GetWindowText()`. And in fact, if a window belongs to another process, [`GetWindowText()` **cant** hang](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030821-00/?p=42833), by design. The only way it can hang is if the window belongs to your own process and the window's message queue is not being processed. That would be a bug in your own code.